# How can I stop all code execution in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
var myVar = 0;


function myFunctionOne() {
    myVar = myVar + 2;
    if(myVar <= 3) {
        alert("all is good");
    } else {
        showError(myVar);
    }
}

function myFunctionTwo() {
    myVar = myVar + 2;
    if(myVar <= 3) {
        alert("all is good");
    } else {
        showError(myVar);
    }
}

function myFunctionThree() {
    //This should never run....
    myVar = myVar + 2;
    if(myVar <= 3) {
        alert("all is good");
    } else {
        showError(myVar);
    }
}

function showError(myVar) {
    alert("Error Var is larger than 3. Var is" + myVar);
    return false; 
//This doesn't seem to stop anything

}

myFunctionOne();
myFunctionTwo();
myFunctionThree();
```

Here is also the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzjk44Lr/

What can I put inside my showError() function, that will kill any subsequent function calls? In this example, myFunctionThree(); should never run.

I know this is a simple example, but I'm trying to get my head around the module pattern, and in my module I have a lot of functions that delegate work, and modify variables. So if one function fails, or is given an illegal variable, I want everything to stop and show the user an error. Because if there was an error in myFunctionOne() for example, there is no point in continuing to execute any of the other code.

I guess, I'm looking for something like the php exit() function. 
Any advice about how to do this, or how I should do it differently would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't do something like php `exit()` because you're not going to shut-down the browser.  This all sounds to me like you need an error handling design for your code rather than a throw your hands up in the error and just abort everything.  You can `throw` an exception and that will stop the current thread of execution (up to any exception handler that might catch the exception), but is not always the best way to design code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**throw**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an error:

```
throw new Error("Error Var is larger than 3. Var is" + myVar);
```

Comment: So, is this the way to do it, or is this just a solution to my problem? What I mean is, is this acceptable JavaScript syntax? Is it ok to have a module with many functions that depend on each other, and if one fails, I kill everything below?

Comment: @Amir - `throw` has it's place in Javascript if used properly.  It sounds to me more like you need to design proper error handling into your functions so one can encounter an error, return that error to its callers and let them decide how to proceed or not based on the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Do you have a real life example of this? I'm just getting started with this and want to adopt good practices. What do you mean by return an error to it's callers. In the above example, who would showError(myVar) return anything to? And to what purpose?

Comment: @Amir - It sounds like you need to study some Javascript basics about returning a value from a function and then testing that return value in the caller.  You can start with [this page about error handling](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter5.html), but it sounds like you really need to study/learn more Javascript basics about return values from functions.  `showError()` can return a value that the function calling it can test (likely using `if ()` statements) so the caller of another function can make decisions based on what the function returns.

Comment: @Amir - a real life example might be you make a function call see if a password meets the minimum requirements (say it's called `checkPassword()`) and the function returns a result that indicates whether the password contains the necessary complexity and length to meet the rules.  The caller of that function examines the return value of the function and then based on that result, it either informs the user that they need a different password or it proceeds on with the rest of the process.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah ok, yes I do get that. First of all, thank you for the link the more I can absorb the better! To your real life example, I guess that was my questions. Let's say "on submit" you have a function that checks password length, and if the password is good it goes on to save the password. But, with the way I'm chaining  functions my save function would run anyway. right? checkpassword() savepassword(), I have them both chained to "on click run userRegistration(). So I wanted to stop everything after checkpassword() if it fails. Or are you saying I should nest all these functions?

Comment: @jfriend00 Nest as in checkpassword() { if check ok...run savePassword()}, but this doesn't seem to be the "module" pattern that I'm trying to adapt, right? Where it says all functions need to be independent. This is what I'm trying to emulate: http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Comment: *"Where it says all functions need to be independent."* Well, `checkPassword` and `savePassword` seem to be independent. The function that calls both of them is the glue. `if (valid) { thenSave(); }` is a perfectly understandable solution. The "module pattern" is for organizing code as a whole. Individual parts still have closer  internal (and looser external) dependencies. You can't (realistically) write code without dependencies.

Comment: @FelixKling ahhhh so you're saying, with my example above I should do this: function master() {
 //Run first function
 myFunctionOne();
 if(...myFunctionOne() came back without errors...) {
  myFunctionTwo();
  if(...myFunctionTwo() came back without erros...) {
   myFunctionThree();
  }
 }
}
 And then maybe even wrap master() inside a try/catch statement?

Comment: @Amir—only use *try..catch* where you expect an error that you can't detect or avoid, e.g. in early IE it was impossible to detect support for XMLHttpRequest without actually calling it, so the call was wrapped in *try..catch*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javascript throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw).

According to Mozilla MDN

> Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.

Example:

```
throw "An error ocurred."
```

You can also go pro and throw an error object like this:

```
throw new MyAppError("custom error str", 128);
```